# How to delete or rename a file while logging information into it?

Tags: java, logging

My application logs data to a file named "log.txt". However, I am unable to rename or delete the file while logging is in progress. I need to be able to rename the file while the application is running, and if the application cannot find "log.txt" on the next logging attempt, a new "log.txt" file will be created. How can I achieve this?

Logger settings

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level     = ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.append    = true
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern   = log.txt
```

Logger declaration

```
static Logger LOGGER;
    static {
        try(FileInputStream ins = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/log.config")) {
            LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(ins);
            LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(BuildGet.class.getName());
            initialContext = new InitialContext();
        } catch (NamingException | IOException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING,"EROOR LOGGER ", e);
        }
    }
```

P.S logger declaration in different classes is the same

Comment: while logging? not. Interrupt the logging, and make sure the file isn't used anymore.

Comment: Use a logging framework. Those usually have log rotation & deletion options to make this easy for you.